# What is the technical terms for the variable assigning or being assigned to, .e.g a = b

Tags: computer-science

I wonder what are the technical terms for the 'assigner' and 'assignee' when assigning a variable to another.

For example:

```
a = b
```

What is the general way to refer `a` and `b` ?

assigner and assignee ?

Best regards,

Comment: Since `=` is (usually) called an *operator*, `a` and `b` would be *operands* and distinguished by their *lefthand* or *righthand* position.

Comment: is there a further way to separate these two operands?I am writing a report that would like to focus on the restrictions b operands. Something like "the assigning operand does not need to have the same shape as the operand being assigned to" Or maybe just the right operand and left operand? Thanks